# BuddyPress plugin for user Authorization

Tags: buddypress

I am looking to use BuddyPress to create a working social network site.  One of the stipulations is that each user will have two different access levels.  When a user views there page, they will be able to see either one or the other.  But not both.  Is there a BuddyPress plugin that will come close to that functionality?

Thanks,
Main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess these links would be a good place to start.

http://wpmu.org/9-new-buddypress-plugins-that-kick-ass/

http://mustech.net/2010/08/the-definitive-list-of-buddypress-plugins-70-listed/